# How to change the value that shows up when an HTML input field spinner is clicked for the first time?

Tags: html, input, spinner, default

I created a survey with an HTML number input field and I would like to change the value that shows up when the number input spinner is clicked or when the user presses up or down ("ArrowUp", "ArrowDown") for the first time.

The below code and the accompanying fiddle provide an example. When the spinner (the buttons on the right side of the input field) is clicked, the number field starts at 0. I would like to be able to change this initial value (e.g., set is to .53).

```
<input type="number" min="-1" max="1" step="0.01" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pkzz6pno/

The input field needs to be empty otherwise (to avoid influencing user responses as much as possible and to make it obvious that the field has not been filled out). Therefore, using "value" or "defaultValue" doesn't lead to the desired solution. Using a placeholder doesn't work either as this does not change the starting value of the spinner.

I also found some add-ons that allow this to be done and some instructions on how to switch the spinner off (http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/) but I was hoping to find a less intrusive solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I undestood you need a solution where initial value appears only after user starts interacting with an input. For that reason I suggest reacting on `input` event. The approach is demonstrated below:

```js
var initialValue = 0.53;
var $spinner = $("#spinner");

function setDefaultValue() {
  $(this).val(initialValue);
  $(this).off("input", setDefaultValue);
}

$spinner.on("input", setDefaultValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="spinner" type="number" min="-1" max="1" step="0.01" />
```

Comment: Great solution! On the site there does seem to be a slight lag. You can actually see the value change from -.01/.01 to .53. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @ColinLee Think I have found a better solution! Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var startVal = 0.53;
  var firstClick = false;
  $("#myId").focus(function() {
    if (!firstClick) {
      $(this).val(startVal);
      firstClick = true;
    }    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myId" type="number" min="-1" max="1" step="0.01" />
```

Here is an example showing a spinner with start value when clicking on it (or by clicking the arrows). Here is the approach :

I used [.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) JQuery function that let me be able to bind an action when user click on every component of the item (such as the arrows in this example).

To be able to not reset the value when clicking out and in again, I used a `boolean`, that is initialized to `false` when DOM is loaded. 
Then, when the user click for the first time, we enter the function that set default value to the spinner and the `var firstClick` that was `false` is changed to `true`. 
When trying to blur and focus again, the function that set a default value is not tiggered because the value of `firstClick` is true.

Since this is a custom behavior, I don't think you can perform such a process without JavaScript. Here I used [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), which is a package tool made from JavaScript plain.